# grub era when loading windows on its own drive

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I have loaded Ubuntu onto a spare usb drive with windows 7 on the main hard drive. I did not opt for a duel boot alonside windows. They were meant to be seperate. I had to alter boot priority on the bios of the mother board.
If i take the usb drive out. Windows wont load and i get a grub era. I think it looks like the boot MBR has been written to my hard drive and not the usb drive with Ubuntu. If that is the case can i solve it without loosing data from my Ubuntu drive or my windows drive. Thanks

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If Windows 7 probably BIOS. Then all you have to do is install a Windows boot loader to MBR of Windows drive and install grub to MBR of external drive. Best to use Something Else install option when installing to avoid that issue.  You can use your Windows repair disk to run fixMBR for Windows. In Ubuntu do this first so you can still boot Ubuntu. Boot into Ubuntu then run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` if exteral drive is sdb. Have both Windows repair disk and Ubuntu install available in case of boot issues. Or use Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Master Boot Record (MBR) on your Windows directory was, indeed, over-written. There are several ways to repair this, depending upon which version of Windows you are using. I would recommend the following webpage, as it lists methods for almost all currently popular Windows desktop versions: https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/

Comment: I will try what you suggested. I did load using the other option, but it was when I re installed. That it altered the boot, before that the two drives could be detached with no boot problems. Thanks

Comment: Yeah all is well now. Used Boot repair to transfer boot Grub back to the USB drive with Ubuntu on. Then used Win 7 disc and fixed MBR. Simple when you know how, thanks for all your help. Just a note to say i have been trying to use Ubuntu for years but always find hardware issues. This version now does it all (16.4) and i love the features it offers. I can do about 90% of my work on it, a bit more usage and i can boot windows in to touch, pun intended. Thanks again

Comment: Excellent--I'm glad things are back to working.